# Are the conductors in UF-B THWN?

Tags: electrical

I have a run of UF-B going to an outdoor wooden post. On that post I have a couple of outlets and a switch.

Once at the post, can I remove the outer sheathing of the UF-B conductors and use them to wire between these items or do I need to buy THWN wire?

Thanks so much.

-samantha

Comment: When you say "wire between these items", are we talking about a bunch of stuff in a single junction box, or a box with outlets in it and a separate box with a switch in it connected by conduit? That distinction matters *hard* here

Comment: Are the individual wires marked with text running along them that says blah blah THWN?

Comment: UF can be spliced in a box and continue up in conduit as thhn/thwn in conduit. Only a non electrician would ask if the wires were labeled!  They are similar to to NMB , but a real electrician would know this... so many internet electricians have no idea OOPS AGAIN !

Comment: @EdBeal My understanding of code is that without labeling, the wires in cable cannot be used (beyond one junction box when you can see the cable jacket) even though they ae otherwise identical to THWN/THHN, precisely **because** they are not labelled, and that makes using them outside of the labeled jacket a code violation. I happen to be sitting on most of a 1000 foot roll of 12/2 that is useless to me because of this interpretation of code, as I opted to go all-conduit in the interest of not having rodent-induced fires. If you can prove me wrong with code cites, I'd be delighted.

Comment: No you are correct the wires are the same but not labeled so they cannot have the cover removed, my comment says a splice in a box and continue with thhn/thwn , not to strip the cable. Can you splice UF ? absolutely!! in fact a splice in the earth (UF) doesn’t require a box but changing to thhn/thwn then a box and conduit would be required from that point. Just tired of all the down votes from internet only electricians so I will be adding comments when I see things like this that a pro would know.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. You've solved my problem and I now know what I need to do to get this wired correctly.